# How to use Gnocchi API on Openstack rocky

Tags: cloud, openstack, ceilometer

I'm trying to use gnocchi API for read metric data.

So I installed Openstack with devstack( I attached a configuration file (local.conf) ). I think I installed ceilometer and gnocchi for collected data. But when i try to read data on API server and CLI, it dones't work. Can you please explain why it doesn't work?

```
[[local|localrc]]

HOST_IP=

ADMIN_PASSWORD=
RABBIT_PASSWORD=
SERVICE_PASSWORD=
DATABASE_PASSWORD=

GIT_BASE=https://git.openstack.org/

NOVA_BRANCH=stable/rocky
NOVACLIENT_BRANCH=stable/rocky
KEYSTONE_BRANCH=stable/rocky
KEYSTONECLIENT_BRANCH=stable/rocky
CINDER_BRANCH=stable/rocky
NEUTRON_BRANCH=stable/rocky
GLANCE_BRANCH=stable/rocky

enable_plugin heat https://git.openstack.org/openstack/heat stable/rocky
enable_plugin heat-dashboard https://git.openstack.org/openstack/heat-dashboard stable/rocky
enable_service h-eng h-api h-cfn h-api-cw heat-dashboard

enable_plugin neutron-lbaas https://git.openstack.org/openstack/neutron-lbaas stable/rocky
enable_plugin neutron-lbaas-dashboard https://git.openstack.org/openstack/neutron-lbaas-dashboard stable/rocky
enable_plugin octavia https://git.openstack.org/openstack/octavia stable/rocky

enable_service q-svc q-agt q-dhcp q-l3 q-meta
enable_service q-lbaasv2 neutron-lbaas-dashboard
enable_service octavia o-cw o-hk o-hm o-api

enable_plugin ceilometer https://git.openstack.org/openstack/ceilometer.git stable/rocky
CEILOMETER_BACKEND=gnocchi

enable_plugin aodh https://git.openstack.org/openstack/aodh stable/rocky
enable_plugin panko https://git.openstack.org/openstack/panko stable/rocky

enable_service c-bak
enable_service swift
```

command 'openstack metric list' works well,
but 'gnocchi metric list' doesn't work at all.
with below message.

Unable to establish connection to http://localhost:8041/v1/metric?: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8041): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/metric (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

also when I post https://localhost/metric/v1/metric (which is API Access say metric URL) with X-Auth-Token as follow gnocchi api says, It doesn't work.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue, can someone please share a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's couse gnocci cli are looking for endpoint like http://servername:8041. 
You should create new endpoints for gnocci service as in documentation https://docs.openstack.org/ceilometer/rocky/install/install-base-rdo.html
Also you should ensure the redis or other backend service is enabled and active